# Find the Quartile.

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics, order-statistics

There are the following numbers from a sample data: $$36, 45, 49, 53, 55, 56, 59, 61, 62, 65, 69, 71, 76, 78, 81, 85, 91, 92, 99.$$ There are $19$ values. The question is to find the third quartile. The answer is $79.5.$

How is that the answer? Can someone please explain how to get that number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *third quartile* is the median between the median and the highest value in the data.  The *median* is the middle value of the data when there are an odd number of values and the average of the two middle values when there are an even number of data.

Since there are $19$ data points and they are listed in increasing order, the median is the tenth value, which is $65$.  Thus, the third quartile is the median of the data $$65, 69, 71, 76, 78, 81, 85, 91, 92, 99$$  Since there are ten values in this set and they are listed in increasing order, the third quartile is the average of the fifth and sixth values, which is $$\frac{78 + 81}{2} = \frac{159}{2} = 79.5$$

Comment: Thank you! That is the better answer. So I guess that means the first quartile is the median between the lowest number and the median?

Answer (score -1):

Note that $Q_3 = P_{75}$. Formula is: $L = \dfrac{k}{100}\cdot n = \dfrac{75}{100}\cdot 19 = 14.25 \approx 15$. Thus the $15$th value of the set is the third quartile , and this value is: $81$.

Comment: Thank you. I got it now :)